# visual studio code doesn't run for-loop when condition is set to i = parameter

Tags: javascript, for-loop, visual-studio-code

i wanted see what the output will be if the condition for executing the code block is `i = num`. when i run the code, vs code terminal just shows `node (path of my file)` and i subsequently cannot execute any code from any file again. i must restart vs code and change the condition to `i < num`. why is this so? **running the code in the code snippet here also seemingly crashes the page.**

is this an infinite loop? however i don't see how it is an infinite loop as the condition to run the code is `i=num`. if `i =/= num`, shouldn't an error be returned instead of crashing vs code?

```js
function FirstFactorial(num) { 
  let solution = 1
  for (let i = 1; i = num; i++){
    solution *= i
  }
  return solution; 
}

console.log(FirstFactorial(5))
```

Comment: [`i = num`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) is an assignment. To check equality, use `i == num`. Since assignments evaluate to the assigned value, using `i = num` as the condition is equivalent to checking the [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) of `num`.

Comment: oh. is there a way to make vs code function again without restarting vs code?

Comment: when i changed to `i==num` the output is only 1. whats the logic behind? since the condition is that `i` must increment till it is `5` before executing the code, shouldn't the output be `solution = 5`?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is the `i = num` in your:

```js
for (let i = 1; i = num; i++){
```

you want `i <= num` for the for loop to iterate.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++){
  solution *= i
}
```

The for loop iterates while the second block `i <= num` evaluates to
`true`.

As soon as its false it will break out of the for loop,
as `1 != 5` (where `num` is `5` in your example)  having `i = num`; as your second block evaluates to false right away and the for statement does not run.

Comment: Hello! Questions that are caused by typos are off-topic on StackOverflow and should be closed, not answered. Answering off-topic questions [is considered harmful to the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions), and [can attract downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions).

Comment: when i changed to `i==num` the output is only 1. whats the logic behind? since the condition is that `i` must increment till it is `5` before executing the code, shouldn't the output be `solution = 5`?

Comment: you want :  i <= num;

Comment: for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++){

Comment: Alex - yes i know about that. i would like to understand the logic of what happens when `i==num`

Comment: That will only evaluate to true if they are the same value, for example lets say you passed FirstFactorial(1), the body of the for statement would run once, and as soon as i>num it wont run again.   If you called FirstFactorial(2) it just would never enter the body of the for as 1 != 2 and your starting of setting i to 1.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to address. The second parameter for the for loop should be a condition.

`i = num`

is not a condition.

If you want to compare those variables you can use the triple ===

Comment: when i changed to `i==num` the output is only 1. whats the logic behind? since the condition is that `i` must increment till it is `5` before executing the code, shouldn't the output be `solution = 5`?